# laravel 5.1 secure_asset 404 error

Tags: php, css, laravel

hey guys I am trying to load some files over an secure network (I am using cloud9 IDE).

I  have the following code here

```
<link href="{{ secure_asset('public/css/cb.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but I am getting this error

> GET https://user-name.c9users.io/public/css/cb.min.css 404 (Not Found)

that file path is correct but I am not sure how to debug from here, still new to laravel. I've tried this as well

```
 <link href="{{ URL::asset('public/css/cb.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://user-name.c9users.io/?' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://user-name.c9users.io/public/css/cb.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

which is chrome preventing insecure files to be loaded, which is why I went with `secure_asset`

any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/cb.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me `secure_asset('css/etc/etc')`